# openstreetmap - change styles based on distance

Tags: openstreetmap

I need to know that is there any way to change the OpenStreetMap chart color combination based on the distance.

like in ABC city if anybody wants to know how many XYZ malls are available near to the location base on latitude and latitude.

for example.

> XYZ mall nearer to latitude and latitude which was entered by the user
>   will highlight in blue color, next nearer to black, next nearer to
>   orange, next nearer to pink and so on.

I like to integrate this map in my one of the website where user enter place and it will highlighted with different colors.

I need to do this using OpenStreetMap so is there any example for doing this? if so, it would be great if you share it here, please.

Thank You,

Comment: For a website? A mobile app? Desktop software? Just a graphic? Please provide more information about your requirements.

Comment: @scai thank you for the response, now I have update the information. Hope you get more info in that.